# How do I filter drop down list and bind first matching item in select drop down list in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select

I have input text box to filter items from a dropdown Select list. 
This works fine.

But there are two problems.

1. When data gets populated i want 1st item to be visible in dropdown.
2. As i type in filter box first matching among the list should be displayes in the dropdown control.

How do i achieve this?

```html
<input type="text" id="fromSearchBox" class="form-control w-auto h-25"
       ng-model="SearchEmployee" />
<select class="form-control" ng-model="fromManagerInfo">
    <option ng-repeat="emp in employees|filter:SearchEmployee">
       {{emp.EmployeeInfo}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selectedItem using ng-model on ng-init

```
<input type="text" ng-init="SearchEmployee = employees[0]" id="fromSearchBox" class="form-control w-auto h-25" ng-model="SearchEmployee" />
```

and for filter you are already using the **`filter`**

Comment: It behaves same. I want to make my dropdown list behaves like auto complete text box.